# How can I display chinese contents from database?

Tags: sql, r

I have created a connection with

```
library(RODBC)
con <- odbcConnect("DV1", uid = "aaa", pwd = "bbb")
```

And implement the SQL command:

```
line.gps <- sqlQuery(con, "SELECT LINE_NAME FROM NJGJ_BUS_TRIP_EX WHERE LINE_NAME IN('2路')")
```

But there is no result:

```
[1] LINE_NAME
<0 行> (或0-长度的row.names)
```

Actually there is data when I implement this sql command in database studio.

Is there any way to impliment it?